# QlikView set analysis with date: nothing result

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a problem with a set analysis in QlikView with the date.

I have created a table that contains the sales order.
One field contains the dates of requesting products.
Now if I use a set analysis to filter the data, I receive 0.
The code used that is not working is below.

If I use a set analysis with one date (see below) I receive the orders that have that date in Ord.Original.Req.Date.

Any suggestion?

code not working:

```
sum({$< Ord.Campain={$(=(max(Ord.Campain)-1))}, 
        Ord.Original.Req.Date = {"$(='<=' & Date(monthend($(vMaxDateAP)), 'DD/MM/YYYY')"}>}
        Ord.T.Amm)
```

code working but with one date:

```
sum({$<[Ord.Original.Req.Date] ={'31/01/2018'}>}Ord.T.Amm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
sum({$< Ord.Campain={"$(=max(Ord.Campain)-1)"}, Ord.Original.Req.Date = {"<=$(=Date(monthend($(vMaxDateAP)), 'DD/MM/YYYY'))"}>}Ord.T.Amm)
```